# Find all urls except markdown link to autolink

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to find all urls to replace them with a markdown link. However, in my string I already have some URLs already wrapped by the markdown syntax. So I need to ignore those cases. Is it possible with JS regex to do that?

Here's what I currently have:

```
(?:[^\]\)]|^)(htt\ps?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))
```

Only the last line of text shouldn't be captured here:
https://regex101.com/r/qgm8jN/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I truncated your regex a little bit (I was trying to remove variables), feel free to add stuff back as you see fit.

https://regex101.com/r/iVQvEu/1

primarily what you need to know is negative look behinds (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?<!not)website`

will match `website` as long as it is not preceded by `not`

so in your case, i used `(?<!\]\()` which looks for `](` and will return the website as long as the markdown symbols are not in front of it.

Again feel free to add/subtract to it, but that should at least point you in the right direction.